# Having difficulty uninstalling World of Warcraft os v 15.10

Tags: 15.10, uninstall, playonlinux

New patch for WoW came out, found that I was prevented from signing in.  Was running the game client through PlayonLinux, stupidly removed it, then tried to reinstall and believe that it loaded (i can get to the login screen) but now cannot access the game (perpetual connection limbo).  I decided to try to uninstall the game and load it back through PlayonLinux, but I don't have enough space on my hard drive to install a new client, which tells me that the old client is still kicking around.  I just have no idea how to find this old game client in order to remove it and free up the necessary space!

Answer (score 0):

Everything you installed under PlayOnLinux is stored under Wine Prefixes at inside the PlayOnLinux folder in your home directory.

The windows programs you installed will be located at `~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/PREFIXNAME/drive_c/Program Files/`

I personally don't play WoW, but PREFIXNAME should probably be WorldOfWarcraft.